# Mysql Query Format Change From ZEND TO Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, yii2

Anyone can help me for change the below query from ZEND format to Yii2 format,

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from(array('u' => 'user'), array('user_id', 'name', 'dob'))
       ->join(array('ua' => 'User_Address'), 'ua.user_id = u.user_id', array())
       ->join(array('a' => 'Address'), 'a.address_id = ua.address_id', array('address_id', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'country'));
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use eg:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    -select(['u.user_id', 'u.name', 'u.dob', Address.street, Address.city , Address.state, Address.country ])
    ->from('user u' ) 
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'User_Address', 'User_Address.user_id = u.id')
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'Address', 'Address.user_id = User_Address.address_id AND ')    
    ->all();
```

see  more at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge , but what I need is that, I have conditions, which when fulfilled will decide the params for select statement(basically columns to be fetched from db need to be added dynamically on fulfillment of some conditions) which is why I have given different columns for each table in Zend is there a point to point conversion avaialable?

Comment: @GThamizh Where is the condition in your original question? Current answer by scaisEdge translates properly Zend query builder into Yii2's query builder.